# GitLab CI schedule task for specific jobs

Tags: gitlab-ci, scheduled-tasks, pipeline

I have several jobs that are set to be triggered only for scheduled tasks. Some job requires to run every hour and other is set to run every day.

How do I set the job to run on schedule and also on specific schedule tasks/definitions? I know GitLab CI has an option to set rules for jobs to run on schedule but I could find an option to set a specific schedule given that I have many scheduled tasks.

For example:

```
job:
  script: echo "Hello, Rules!"
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
      when: manual
      allow_failure: true
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule"
```

The rule `- if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule"` is very generic. I don't want some job to run every hour. I want it to pick the schedule that is set to run every day only for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a new schedule with a variable and change gitlab-ci.yml . For example:

```
job:
  script: echo "Hello, Rules!"
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
      when: manual
      allow_failure: true
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule" && $SCHEDULE_TIMING == "hourly"
```

and add new schedule with variable

[image]